# How to perform a button action with a key press in extjs?

Tags: extjs

I have a form in which I enter details in the fields and press on the "Search" button, it checks if the fields are entered properly. Based on that it either searches or prompts the user to enter additional details. Pretty standard. Now I want to perform the same action so that when the user hits the **ENTER** key the same "search" actions are performed. I searched a lot online but couldnt find anything substantial for this.

```
 {
                            xtype : 'button',
                            text : 'Search',
                            handler : function() {
                             //search function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.

1.
If you want to call search button functionality on press enter, then you can use specialkey listener.

First create a common function in this file or in separate file.
Ex.

```
function sample()
{
  // coding
}

function sample2(el, e)
{
  if (e.keyCode == e.ENTER) {
    sample();
    e.stopEvent();
}
}

{
xtype : 'button',
text : 'Search',
handler : sample //sample function will be called
}

{
xtype:'textfield',
id: 'txtId',
listener:{
specialkey: sample2 
}
}
```

When "sample2" function will be called on press enter, first it will check when it's enter key press or any other, then it will sample function (in which you can actual code that will work on button click or enter press on text field).

Answer (score 0):

use keymap

```
new Ext.util.KeyMap({
    target: "yourDOmElement"/ your component,
    key: Ext.EventObject.ENTER
    fn: handler
});
```

sample:

```
var x = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {renderTo: Ext.getBody()});
var map = new Ext.util.KeyMap({
    target: x.getEl(),
    key: 13,
    fn: function() {alert();}
});
```